# Area of Shaded Region

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inequality, area

I am using the Pearson Edexcel A-Level maths books for my A-Level studies and stumbled across a question I do not understand (Exercise 3G Question 8d).

The last part of the question confused me since it asked me to calculate the area of the shaded region. I checked the solution bank after attempting the question and found that it was using the area of two triangles and taking away the distance between them, despite the smaller triangle not being a right-angled triangle and no angles being provided, hence my confusion.

Below is the question in full, a diagram of what I have mentioned above along with the coordinates of each vertices.

##### Question

**8.)**

a.) On a coordinate grid, shade the region which satisfies the following inequalities
$y \lt x + 4$, $y + 5x + 3 \ge 0$, $y \ge 1$ and $x \lt 2$

b.) Work out the coordinates of the vertices of the shaded region

c.) Which of the vertices lie within the region identified by the inequalities?

d.) Work out the area of the shaded region.

##### Diagram

[Diagram of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnMDg.png)

##### Coordinates of Verticies

$$A = (-7/6, 17/6),
B = (2, 6),
C = (-2/5, -1),
D = (2, -1)$$

##### My Confusion

I understand to do this finding the distance between the points B and D is 7, and D and C is also 7, therefore the area of the large right-angled triangle which can be seen in the diagram is $49\over2$.

The part which has stumped me is how the area of the region would be found since as mentioned before there is no angle given and the other triangle enclosed within the area calculated is not a right-angled triangle. However, the solution bank claims the following is the solution.

[Solution bank answer for question 8d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNrIG.png)

I assume I am missing something but I cannot work out what.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of your question says $y>1$ but the attached figure shows $y>-1.$  I will assume that $y>-1$ is correct.

As far as finding the area.  I suggest breaking this quadrilateral in two at the line $y = \frac {17}{6}$

Now you have a triangle and a trapezium, and you have formula for both of these.

Triangle: $A = \frac 12 bh = \frac 12 (\frac {19}{6})(\frac {19}{6})$
Trapezium: $A = \frac 12 (b_1 + b_2)h = \frac 12 (\frac {17}{6} + \frac {12}{5})(\frac {23}{6})$

Alternatively, you could use the shoelaces algorithm.  Put the points an array in counterclockwise order.

$\begin {array}\\
2&6\\
-\frac 76& \frac {17}6\\
-\frac 25&-1\\
2&-1\\
2&6\end {array}$

Repeating the first row at the end.
Now multiply pairs diagonally, add the numbers you get when multiplying Northwest/Southeast and subtract the ones from multiplying Southeast/Northwest.  Divide the result by 2.

$\frac {\frac {17}{3} + 7 + \frac {7}{6}+\frac {34}{30} + \frac {2}{5} + 2 + 12 +2}{2}$

As far as the solution bank solution goes, (I found my solutions before looking at that, that works better for me) They found the area of the triangle bounded by the red, green, and black lines, and subtracted the area of the triangle bounded by the red, blue, and black lines. This triangle with the red, blue, and black lines, while it is not a right triangle and no angle is given, we can still find base and height

Answer (score 2):

Let $E = (-5,-1)$. The solution seemingly claims something like
$A = A_{\Delta EDB} - A_{\Delta ECA}$. $EDB$ is a right triangle and for $ECA$ they use $A_{ECA} = \frac{|EC| \cdot h}{2}$ where $h$ is the height over $EC$

Answer (score 1):

The solution clearly uses the sine theorem. You can use the points of intersection with x and y axis to get the sine value and use the sine theorem to get the area of the unshaded triangle:

$\frac{1}{2}ab\sin\alpha$

To get the lengths of these two edges |AC| and (referring to the intersection of $y=-1$ and $y=x+4$ as E) |CE| you can calculate the intersection points and use the Pythagorean theorem, then use the said equation to get the area and subtract from the larger triangle.